# Seekbar sync with timer

Tags: java, android

I am new at programming in Android and I am trying to figure out how to link the seekbar with my timer.  In my program I allow the user to put in a time then click start timer, which then sends that value to a TextView and decrements seconds until finished.  I would like the seekbar to "follow" along.  Any help would be appreciated!

I've got the seekbar to sort of follow the timer but now its too choppy... is there an easy way to make a smooth progress?

```
public void startTimer() {
    int min = Integer.parseInt(edit_minute.getText().toString());
    int sec = Integer.parseInt(edit_second.getText().toString());
    int value = (min * 60) + sec;
    seek_bar.setMax(value *10000);

    new CountDownTimer(getValues(), 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            text1.setText(""
                    + String.format(
                            FORMAT,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)
                                    - TimeUnit.HOURS
                                            .toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                                    .toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                            .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                                    .toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            seek_bar.setProgress((seek_bar.getProgress() + 1));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            text1.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update it from your `CountDownTimer`. First, create an instance variable:

```
SeekBar progressBar;
```

Within your `onCreate`, get a reference to the seek bar:

```
progressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_current);
```

Once you start the timer, tell `progressBar` the maximum it should go to:

```
progressBar.setMax(); // How ever long the timer will run for
```

Then in the `CountDownTimer`, update the progress:

```
progressBar.setProgress(); // The total time, minus millisUntilFinished
```

Comment: Thanks I added: `seek_bar.setProgress(seek_bar.getProgress() + 1);` because setProgress only takes integers.  Do you know of another way?